# Display all predictions and their percentages in the title of a figure

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, classification, figure

Im working on a project in deep learning. I have two variables for storing predictions and their percentages. 
This is done using a for loop for every image in a cell array C. Both predictions and percentages are stored in separate column vectors which Ill need for later use

```
for i=1:size(C)

img=im2uint8(C{i});
img2=imresize(img,[224 224]);
[prediction,pred_val] = classify(n_net,img2)
predictions(i,:)=prediction;
pred_vals(i,:)=pred_val;
figure
imshow(img2)

title(sprintf("%s %s",[labels,num2str(100*pravdepodobnost_predikciesnimky(i,:))]));
end
```

Now, I want to display all of the predictions and percentages, so lets say the network predicts that image consists of 80%ocean and 20% people, so the title in the figure displays both predictions not just the dominant one. Which is the best way to do this?

Edit: here is a sample for clarification (the titles and labels are in my native language):

```
labels=string(categories(scenes_training.Labels)') %creates 1x2 string array
labels = 
"Pobrežie"    "Ulica"
```

After one iteration from the for loop above I get this:

```
prediction = categorical
 Ulica

pred_vals = 1×2 single row vector    
0.0046    0.9954
```

And (after modification) a [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMHxK.png)

So my goal is to write the title like this:

**Pobrežie 0.45644 %; Ulica 99.5436 %**

Comment: It would help to know what the data in `predictions` looks like (`pred_vals` is fairly obvious).

Comment: @EuanSmith it is a column string vector with only one column (so a nx1 matrix) where the prediction is sotred every iteration and it looks like this: 

sea
sea
people
sea
people
sea

, cant write it here as a column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the variables described above then you can use [`sprintf`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) to do what you want.

```
% Use the dummy data from above
labels = ["Pobrežie", "Ulica"];
pred_vals = [0.0046, 0.9954];
% now format a string to use as a title
img_title=sprintf("%s %s%%; ", [labels', num2str(100*pred_vals')]');
%img_title now equals "Pobrežie  0.46%; Ulica 99.54%; "
```

Basically sprintf will cycle through all values it is supplied with, repeating the string format until it is done.  You can use this to list the contents of a matrix of data.  Putting the data in a matrix and transposing it is just a way of interleaving the names and the values.

The nested transposing in the sprintf input arguments is just to persuade matlab to deal correctly with the different value types - it is a little hacky but then MATLAB often is.  If I can find a nicer way then I'll update the answer.

If you don't want the final "; " at the end of the string, then you can trim that off with a subsiquent step.

Comment: I think I forgot to mention that pred_vals is a nx2 vector with two columns representing two classes (or labels) (eg 1st prediction is sea and its pred_val may be 0.9     0.1) . and  Im just realizing that it is quite impossible (?) to do what I want or I need to use stored labels from training phase?

Comment: I just created a new variable called labels which is a 1x2 string matrix containing 'sea' 'people'. now it should work so that every row in labels is associated to each row from pred_vals but I get the Error using horzcat
Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent.

Comment: @DenisBenka Provide some dummy code which populates the variables with realistic data and give an example of exactly you would like the output to be - this makes the problem _very_ clear.  I am sure there is a way to do it.

Comment: I did it! I made some changes to your solution to work with the loop and it works. the title looks like this: title(sprintf("%s %s%%; ", [labels', num2str(100*pred_vals(i,:)')]'));

Comment: Thank you very much. Im not quite good with that many transposed matrices.. :-)